# Why Brahma Kumaris encourages woman to restrain from sex?

Tags: sex, brahmakumaris

It is obvious from the name of the organization that it is mainly a women-centric organization. Also, the name suggests that they give stress on restraining from sex. Indeed they do precisely what their name suggests. They recommend complete celibacy. Here is what their [website](http://www.brahmakumaris.org/about-us/faqs) says -

> "Celibacy is seen as the basis for cultivating a safe and pure way for people to be and live together. This choice can make people stronger in themselves, more autonomous and more self-confident. It liberates both genders from their over-reliance on each other and supports greater equality. The Brahma Kumaris view celibacy as fundamental to self-realization and to recreating a loving relationship with God and to creating a culture of peace and non-violence."

However, Hinduism never criticized what is natural. Vedas, Tantras, Smritis never looked down with contempt on procreation.

Also, just going by common sense, if they do not have sex, how they are supposed to have a society in the first place?

Comment: Is this for all women or women ascetics? Most of the methods for self realization require celibacy. Is the above paragraph is meant for women ascetics?

Comment: @GIRIBLR For everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [animated movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXqT8TH-fM8) from Brahma Kumaris, they have explained their worldview. They also believe in the 4 Yugas. However, the duration of each Yuga is very short in comparison to the traditional Hindu view. Each Yuga consists of 1250 human years. Now we are at the very end of the Kaliyuga. At the end of Kaliyuga, Satyuga will begin.

The traditional Hindu view is that the end of Kali-yuga will be brought by the Kalki avatar of Vishnu. In contrast, Brahma Kumaris think that by meditation, swatvik living, celibacy and austerity, the mass population will bring the Satyuga.

According to their belief, in sat yuga, human beings did not identify themselves with their body. They knew that they are eternal souls. The world was a very happy and prosperous place. **The babies were created just by mere thought ("Sankalpa").** Gradually the power of souls diminished due to repeated birth. **In Dwapara, the souls identified them with their bodies. So they felt attraction towards each other's bodies. From then, physical conjugation was needed to create new lives.**

Comment: I don't think they have any scriptural proofs for these: "*sankalpa* initiated pregnancies" in the age of Sata-yuga, at-least for normal humans. Normal humans (*Manushyas*) in all age require biological means for progeny. Also, this '1250 years for each yuga' concept seems pure self-cooked conjectures by them. One question though: Do you know, their views on Vedas? How much they subscribe to them?

Comment: How can Yug be of 1250 years ? That would mean Mahabharat happened before even Dwapar Yug .

Comment: @Vivikta Brahma Kumaris do not follow Hindu scriptures. They follow their founder. They call him Prajapita Brahma Baba. He was a merchant from Sindh, Pakistan. In my humble opinion, their procreation theory is the height of absurdness.

Comment: @compaq Yes, it is very strange!!! It just takes 5000 years to complete one cycle.

Comment: So, basically they cannot be regarded as purely Astika school then, I guess? I have heard some of their discourses too, where they kind of equate the *NirAkAr Shiva* to their founder.

Comment: @Vivikta. Yes. You are absolutely right. They call their God Shiva Baba. He is formless and he is light. They say, that in Dwapara Yuga when people started identifying themselves with Bodies, they start erecting Shiva Lingas. As at that time, they can't think anything beyond the body, they added body to God also (in the form of Linga).

Comment: @Vivikta However, their God does not incarnate. It does not subject itself to birth and death. So it speaks to its children through some agents, such as Brahma Baba. It considers Shankaracharya, Buddha, Jesus, Nanak as wiser souls who came to this world to spread the eternal message.

Comment: Also, they deny the "divine" status of *RAma* & *Krishna*, saying they're not gods but just regular "superhumans/enlightened men"

Comment: @Vivikta I guess something similar to Shankaracharya or Nanak. Just enlightened souls.